# How to show and hide a Text Block in Universal Windows Apps 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

In a Windows Universal Apps 8.1 platform targeting Windows Store 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 I need to hide a Text Block that says "The list is empty" when a collection bound to a `ListView` has some items in it and I need to show this Text Block whenever the collection is empty.

Please suggest a solution for this.

So far I've tried this but it doesn't work when there are items in the collection the element *TasksEmptyMsg* still shows that "The list is empty".

```
<Page
    x:Class="ToDoer.Pages.Task"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ToDoer.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView x:Name="Tasks"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TasksItemTemplate}"
                  Padding="24,24">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TaskSelectionChanged}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListView>

        <TextBlock x:Name="TasksEmptyMsg"
                   Text="The list is empty"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                   Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextBlockStyle}">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=Tasks,Path=Items.Count}" 
                                          Value="0">
                    <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=TasksEmptyMsg}" 
                                               PropertyName="Visibility" 
                                               Value="Visible"/>
                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
        <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
            aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
            account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
            if the System Tray is hidden.

            Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
        <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add"
                          Label="add todo"
                          Command="{Binding AddTask}"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Works fine when there are no items in the collection.

[image]

Issue: Shows "The list is empty" even when it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ListView* itself doesn't have any property informing that it's empty, nor binding to *Items.Count* help here, as the property change is not raise. Thankfully it's not hard to implement such mechanism and there are couple of ways to do it. Here is a one that uses *Converters*:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibility x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="TheList" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" Visibility="{Binding IsTasksEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, ConverterParameter='INVERT'}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="EmptyText" Grid.Column="0" Text="List is empty" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsTasksEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Content="Add item" Click="AddButton_Click" Margin="20"/>
            <Button Content="Delete item" Click="DelButton_Click" Margin="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and code behind:

```cs
public class BoolToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => (bool)value != ((string)parameter == "INVERT") ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public ObservableCollection<string> Tasks { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Starting item" };
    public bool IsTasksEmpty => Tasks.Count < 1;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Tasks.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => RaiseProperty(nameof(IsTasksEmpty));
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Tasks.Add("Next item");
    private void DelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Tasks.RemoveAt(Tasks.Count - 1);
}
```

Here is a one for *UWP* that uses *VisualStates* and collection changed event (taking a look at your code I assume that you are using *ObservableCollection* for `Tasks`). XAML code:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ListStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="ListWithItems"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ListEmpty">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="EmptyText.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="TheList.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding IsTasksEmpty}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="TheList" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="EmptyText" Grid.Column="0" Text="List is empty" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Content="Add item" Click="AddButton_Click" Margin="20"/>
        <Button Content="Delete item" Click="DelButton_Click" Margin="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

the code behind is the same as above in solution with converter.

A working sample for *UWP* you will [find at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/UWPSamples/tree/master/EmptyListTrigger).

Comment: There are no Setters, StateTriggers properties on VisualState in windows univeral apps, I'm getting a xaml error, looks like the solution you posted is for windows universal platform and I am using windows universal apps

Comment: @AbdulMateenMohammed Yeah, I thought they were also in Win-RT, it's not hard to change this, give me a moment.

Comment: @AbdulMateenMohammed The version with converters, works in WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this in XAML but so far I wasn't able to do it, so I tried another way i.e. binding the Visibility property of the TextBlock by using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

I set up a property called AreTasksEmpty, and property notification is done through the use of MvvmLight library.

```
/// <summary>
/// The are tasks empty.
/// </summary>
private bool _areTasksEmpty;

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the are tasks empty.
/// </summary>
public bool AreTasksEmpty
{
    get
    {
        return this._areTasksEmpty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Set(ref this._areTasksEmpty, value);
    }
}
```

In the method that fetches the tasks I had updated the property AreTasksEmpty's value as follows.

```
if (this.Tasks.Any())
{
    this.AreTasksEmpty = false;
}
else
{
    this.AreTasksEmpty = true;
}
```

In the XAML, I've done the binding to `Visibility` property as follows,

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TasksEmptyMsg"
           Text="The list is empty"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Visibility="{Binding AreTasksEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
           Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextBlockStyle}">
</TextBlock>
```